# Office.js Office.context.ui.messageParent not working in Excel

Tags: excel, office-js

We have an excel add-in hosted in azure where the Office.context.ui.messageParent API messages aren't being sent/received on the desktop. There's no errors, the message just doesn't get caught at the event listener.

We use the dialog for MFA and we have it working locally for both desktop and web but when we deploy to a stage add-in hosted in azure this issue occurs just on the desktop.

This works:

- dialog url (https://localhost:3000/dist/callback.html)
- taskpane url (https://localhost:3000/dist/taskpane.html)

This doesn't:

- dialog url (https://ip-dev-custom-functions.azurewebsites.net/addin/callback.html)
- taskpane url (https://ip-dev-custom-functions.azurewebsites.net/addin/taskpane.html)

Surprisingly the DialogEventReceived is being triggered but not the message DialogMessageReceived.

callback.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private, no-cache, no-store"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    if (window.opener)
        window.opener.postMessage({type: 'interstitial', url: document.location.href}, "*");

    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        console.log("Sending auth complete message through dialog: " + document.location.href);
        Office.context.ui.messageParent(document.location.href);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

snippet of the taskpane.html where's the event listener:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {
    height: dim.height,
    width: dim.width,
    promptBeforeOpen: false
}, async (result) => {
    _loginDialog = result.value;
    _loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
    _loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, (ev) => {
        console.log("## EVENT RECEIVED ##", ev);
    });
});

function processMessage(arg) {
    console.log("Message received in processMessage: " + JSON.stringify(arg));
    _lastCallback(arg.message);
    _loginDialog?.close();
    _loginDialog = null;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe connected to recent change. See [Cross-domain messaging to the host runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#cross-domain-messaging-to-the-host-runtime). From your URLs, it doesn't seem like your are sending cross-domain, but try adding `{targeDomain: "*"}` as a second parameter to the call of messageParent. Also, are you working on desktop Excel or Excel on the web?

Comment: Hey @RickKirkham! Ok will try that. We are having this issue just on Desktop. Do you think it could be the version of the office js API? The version we use currently there's no option for a second argument using Office.context.ui.messageParent.

Comment: @JoséSalgado I have the same problem as you get. I try the add the secound parameter to the `DialogMessageReceived` but the result is the same. Also i have opened a issue @OfficeDev github repo but without sucess. Here is the link https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1864

Comment: @SérgioSereno thanks for sharing. Will keep an eye on it since I still didn't find a solution. Obrigado 

Comment: @RickKirkham updating the package @types/office-js to latest brought the options argument but no luck, still not working. Not sure if it helps but we have a working add-in locally for both desktop/web so the issue is just when gets deployed to a stage add-in hosted in azure and just affects the desktop. It's exactly the same code, just changes the dialog/taskpane URLs.. very strange

Comment: @JoséSalgado Problem solved. I will close my git ussie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Authenticate and authorize with the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api), the correct flow is:

The add-in should launch the page in the dialog in add-in's domain, then redirect to the sign-in page, and then redirect to another page with the same domain as the first page in dialog again.

Otherwise, the messageParent API won't work, because it only trust the domain of the page used in the displayDialogAsync() API. In your scenario, the sign-in page (launched first time in the dialog) and the callback page are in different domains, which causes the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: @Kejing Peng It works for me too. May thanks.